# javascript proto-chaining confusion on this

Tags: javascript

While going over below tutorial code

```
Animal = function(name) {this.name = name}
Animal.prototype.eats = function(){
      return this.name + ' is eating'
}

Chordate = function(name){Animal.call(this,name)}
```

I understand how `call` works (basically, in this case, this becomes `this`)... but my question is, how does one use this?
I am sorry, I understand how prototype works.. But really, I don't understand once you setup Chordate as above.. how does one use it?
How is this useful? or How are you now suppose to specify the `this`?
Can someone please explain w/ example?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) has some good examples for when you might want to use this.

Comment: Youre missing Chordate.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)

Comment: reading the MDN now..  so   new Chordate(`whatever uwant as this`, arg)

Comment: where is `name` coming from in that example then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a link to `Animal`'s prototype methods:

```
Chordate.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
```

Then `new` it up:

```
var c = new Chordate('my name');

c.eats();
```

The line `Animal.call(this,name)` is like making a call to a base constructor. It executes the `Animal` constructor function and passes in `name`, but uses the correct `this` context:

```
Animal = function(name) {
    // "this" will be your Chordate instance
    this.name = name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine youre constructing an Animal:

```
 new Animal();
```

and during construction it draws a new animal onto the canvas. The constructor would look like this:

```
 function Animal(){
   canvas.draw(this.x,this.y,this.image);
  }
```

Now youve got a tiger. The tiger should roar if it is constructed.

```
 function Tiger(){
   this.roar();
 }
```

And now? Its an animal so its added to the canvas right? No. Because of js inheritance system, you need to do this manually. So when the tiger gets constructed, you also need to construct it as an animal:

```
 Animal.call(this);
```

This is even easier with the new class syntax:

```
 class Animal{
   constructor(){
     this.draw(this.x,this.y,this.image);
   }
}

class Tiger extends Animal{
  constructor(){
    this.roar();
    super()//construct Animal
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is just meant to be an addition to the other answers, and would be too long for a comment.*

Perhaps it helps you to understand what the `new` operator actually does:

```js
var newInstance = new ConstructorFunction(arg1, arg2);
```

1. Create a new object. The prototype of this object is `ConstructorFunction.prototype`:

```js
var newInstance = Object.create(ConstructorFunction.prototype);
```

2. Call the `ConstructorFunction` with the newly created object:

```js
ConstructorFunction.call(newInstance, arg1, arg2);
```

If `ConstructorFunction` inherits from another "class", it has to call its super constructor. That's what the following code does:

```js
function Parent () {
  // this === newInstance
}

function Child () {
  // this === newInstance
  Parent.call(this); // call the super constructor
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

var newInstance = new Child();
// or:
var newInstance = Object.create(Child.prototype);
Child.call(newInstance); // call the constructor, which calls the super constructor
```

Comment: REALLY like this .. HOwever, can you create step one without ConstructorFunction?  Can it be Object.create(Object.prototype) ? I want from scratch and not having to rely anything previously to understand this.. can it be this?

Comment: If it's `Object.create(Object.prototype)`, then you won't get the methods from `ConstructorFunction.prototype`. Of course, you can do that, but I don't think that's what you want. And it's not how the `new` operator works.

Comment: really like this angle.. but let me come back to this.. reading some more on this topic now